# Functional Component based simple form how to get values of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. Have been learning ReactJS since January. Came across a question on function based form, I am unable to get the values typed by the user. Please help.
This is the question...
A form template is given to you. Upon submitting, the information should be displayed in a list below (automatically sorted by last name) along with all the previous information that was entered.

I did an "alert({fname})", but it does not show the content of what the user entered....could you pleaes help me. I am just a beginner in ReactJS.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const style = {
  table: {
    borderCollapse: 'collapse'
  },
  tableCell: {
    border: '1px solid gray',
    margin: 0,
    padding: '5px 10px',
    width: 'max-content',
    minWidth: '150px'
  },
  form: {
    container: {
      padding: '20px',
      border: '1px solid #F0F8FF',
      borderRadius: '15px',
      width: 'max-content',
      marginBottom: '40px'
    },
    inputs: {
      marginBottom: '5px'
    },
    submitBtn: {
      marginTop: '10px',
      padding: '10px 15px',
      border:'none',
      backgroundColor: 'lightseagreen',
      fontSize: '14px',
      borderRadius: '5px'
    }
  }
}

function PhoneBookForm({ addEntryToPhoneBook }) {
    const [fname,setFname] = useState("");
    const [lname, setLname] = useState("");
    const [uphone, setUphone] = useState("");

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => { 
        e.preventDefault();
        alert({fname});
        //alert(${fname});
        //console.log({fname});
        }}
        style={style.form.container}>
        
      <label>First name:</label>
      <br />
      <input 
        style={style.form.inputs}
        className='userFirstname'
        name='userFirstname' 
        type='text'
        placeholder='Coder'
        onChange={e => setFname(e.target.value)}
        value={fname}
      />
      <br/>
      <label>Last name:</label>
      <br />
      <input 
        style={style.form.inputs}
        className='userLastname'
        name='userLastname' 
        type='text' 
        placeholder='Byte'
        onChange={e => setLname(e.target.value)}
        value={lname}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Phone:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        style={style.form.inputs}
        className='userPhone' 
        name='userPhone' 
        type='text'
        placeholder='8885559999'
        onChange={e => setUphone(e.target.value)}
        value={uphone}
      />
      <br/>
      <input 
        style={style.form.submitBtn} 
        className='submitButton'
        type='submit' 
        value='Add User' 
      />
    </form>
  )
}

function InformationTable(props) {
  return (
    <table style={style.table} className='informationTable'>
      <thead> 
        <tr>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>First name</th>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>Last name</th>
          <th style={style.tableCell}>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead> 
    </table>
  );
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <section>
      <PhoneBookForm />
      <InformationTable />
    </section>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
        
export default App;
```

Thank you,

Comment: `alert({fname});` => `alert(fname);`

Comment: When asking for help, please **reduce** the problem to its **minimal form**, more here: [mcve]. Also, making your example runnable using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) makes it easier for people to help you. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

remove all you put inside onSubmit in the form,
take them out and put them into a function expression

like this:

```
const handleUserInput = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert(fname);
   alert(lname);
   alert(uphone);
}
```

change form to this:

```
<Form onSubmit={handleUserInput} style={style.form.container}>
```

lastly, just being cautious, wrap all 'e' used with onChange with parenthesis
like this:

```
onChange={(e) => setFname(e.target.value)}
```

Goodluck with react js

Comment: Still no luck. I am using codesandbox.io playground. When I do  const [fname,setFname] = useState(""); it says (0 , _react.useState) is not a function.

Comment: Hi Ridwan, thanks, This is the codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-hc6j5

Comment: @isaac your code is working,  the problem comes down to your dependencies react and react-dom, I deleted them and installed version "17.0.2", your code worked instantly.  

if you are working locally, delete your node_module, then install  react and react-dom v "17.0.2" --- you are good to go ;

my codesandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-f6jl1?file=/package.json:201-209

cheers!

Comment: Thanks Ridwan, really appreciated, Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right, looks like only one thing cause the problem,

```
alert({fname})
```

it should be

```
alert(fname)
```

without curly braces.
How to use curly braces you can read more detailed at jsx [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)